# how to decode html in specific element before displaying popup window?

Tags: javascript, smarty, popupwindow

I have the following two javascript functions, inside smarty code, with which I want to display a popup window with dynamic content that includes html markup:

1st function for opening the popup window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
// global variable for subwindow reference
var newWindow;
// generate and fill the new window
{literal}
function makeNewWindow( ) {
 // make sure it isn't already opened
 if (!newWindow || newWindow.closed) {
   newWindow = window.open("", "prd_window", "height=400, width=300, fullscreen, resizable");
  // delay writing until window exists in IE/Windows
  setTimeout("writeToWindow( )", 50);
 } else if (newWindow.focus) {
        // window is already open and focusable, so bring it to the front
  newWindow.focus( );
    }
}
{/literal}
```

2nd function for writing dynamic content to the popup window, which is called from the 1st function:

```
function writeToWindow( ) {ldelim}
            // assemble content for new window    
            var newContent = "<html><head><title>title text here</title></head>";
            newContent += "<body>";
            var full_descr = "{$markup_info.fulldescr|strip|escape:'html'}";  
            newContent += "<div id=\"div_fulldescr\">" + full_descr + "</div>";
            newContent += "</body></html>";    
            // write HTML to new window document
            newWindow.document.write(newContent);
            newWindow.document.close( ); // close layout stream
       {rdelim}
</script>
```

In the 2nd function I encode the html markup contained in the **full_descr** variable using the 'escape' smarty modifier, so javascript code doesn't break.
**$markup_info** is a smarty associative array and **fulldescr** is one of it's indexes.

The above code popups a window with the content of the **div_fulldescr** element displaying as html markup, as expected, ie, it has not been decoded.
I was wondering how could I decode the html markup of the **div_fulldescr** div element, before displaying the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to replace `{$markup_info.fulldescr|strip|escape:'html'}` with `{$markup_info.fulldescr|escape:'javascript'}`.

Comment: Great, appreciate the help. I hadn't known about the 'javascript' escape mode - maybe I was reading the smarty documentation v.2. So, as I realize, it is not necessary to decode the encoded code. It gets decoded by the browser itself?

Comment: right. escape:"javascript" simply converts your string to something that is parsable by javascript (i.e. escaping quotes and newlines)